# get the inner html using php from the given html code

Tags: php

This is a very basic question but could not found answer

I want to get the inner html using php from the following html code

```
<strong class="large t55">text only</strong>
```

I want to echo "text only" in simple text not in bold.

Comment: the strong tag will make it Bold!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
echo strip_tags('<strong class="large t55">text only</strong>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get just inner text, `strip_tags` fastest and easiest solution.

But for parsing HTML in general (f.e. to get attributes: name, class, ...) best solution is [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try [HTML DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
<?php 
  $html= "<strong class='large t55'>text only</strong>";

  $dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
  $dom->loadHTML($html); 

  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
  $hTwo= $dom->getElementsByTagName('strong'); 
  echo $hTwo->item(0)->nodeValue; 
 ?>
```